# Oracle 10g Failover Database - How to fail back?

Tags: failover, disaster-recovery, oracle10g, database-backup

I want to know how the failover database concept works after recovery. We have defined our application to connect to a backup database in case the production database fails. If this happens, then all the transactions will be happening on that backup database. Once the production db server is running again, then how do we make sure the changes made in the backup database will be reflected on the production database? We want to make sure that any changes made while failed over are not lost. We are using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing for replication?  We're using a two way streams replication, so we just wait for the main database to get back up to date and then switch connections back.

Comment: @JOTN...I'm not sure what two way streams replication means and what we are currently doing. It was written by someone else and I am working on few modifications. Currently the failover database location is defined in tomcat's server.xml "Resource" element.
<Resource name="or_ds" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container" url="jdbc:inetora:XXXXXXX.com:1530?service=XXXX&amp;failover=true&amp;host1=YYYYY.com&amp;port1=1530&amp;host2=ZZZZZZZ.wellsfargo.com&amp;port2=1530" password="a" maxActive="4" maxWait="5000" diverClassName= "com.inet.ora.OraDriver" username="legalusr" maxIdle="2" />